Grafana Loki QL how to get multiple occurance of a string from the logs & put them as a fields to display in Grafana Dashboard
I have a scenario where I have a need to extract ID's which follow a pattern "PAXXXXXX".Please note the number of these ID's in a log isnt fixed. I can certainly write regex (regexp) to extract them (PA followed by 6 number_ but the problem here is it is fetching only first occurance of this string.  Can you please help me extracting all the occurance of this string pattern?
tried below:
| regexp (?P<Idnumber>[PA\d{6}]) | lineformat {{.Idnumber}}.
But it is only giving me first result. The logs looks like this ...
XXXsdfsfdsfsffs..... PA134567 .... ddfghjttesd ...... PA4567899 ...
Thanks.
